# Output for creating a 2d array of characters doesot come as expected

Tags: java, arrays

> Given a para of words (separated by space), create a 2D array where each array in it represents the word. Note that the words are of the same size.

## Sample Input #1

to2DChars("bat sat put mat")

Sample Output #1

{{'b','a','t'},{'s','a','t'},{'p','u','t'},{'m','a','t'}}

## Sample Input #2

to2DChars("hi is to")

Sample Output #2

{{'h','i'},{'i','s'},{'t','o'}}

**MyApproach**

I first calculated the rows and columns in the string and then I created a new array and inserted each character of the string into the new array.

But I am not getting the expected output.

> Can Anyone guide me why?

```
public char[][] to2DChars(String words)
{
   int countrows=1;
   int countcolumns=0;
   for(int i=0;i<words.length();i++)
   {
       char ch=words.charAt(i);
       if(ch==' ')
       {
           countrows++;
       }
   }
   for(int i=0;i<words.length();i++)
   {
       char ch=words.charAt(i);
      if(ch!=' ')
      {
          countcolumns++;
      }
      else
      {
          break;
      }
   }     
   char c[][]=new char[countrows][countcolumns];
   for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;i<c[i].length;j++)
       {
           char ch1=words.charAt(j);
           c[i][j]=ch1;
       }
   }
      return c;      
 }
}
```

```
 Parameters           Actual Output    Expected Output

'bat sat put mat'      null         {{'b','a','t'};{'s','a','t'};

                                    {'p','u','t'};{'m','a','t'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is too messy...simple step you can take is split String by space using split() method of String class and then convert each word into character array using toCharArray() method of String.

```
public static char[][] to2DChars(String words)
{

   String[] array = words.split("\\s+");
   char[][] chara= new char[array.length][];
   int i=0;
   for(String a : array) {
   chara[i] = a.toCharArray();
           i++;
   }
   return chara;
 }
```

Comment: Please mark the solution as ACCEPTED if your problem is solved...In this way it will help others looking for similar problem..

Comment: It didn't SOLVED my problem.What went wrong in my code.Thank you for the reference but right now I am looking for "WHAT WENT WRONG IN MY CODE".+1 for your simple approach.